# Returned JSON data undefined when using PDO with bindParam

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I've been all over stackoverflow trying to figure this out. I'm using jQuery's `ajax` method to send in some form data, and PDO to prepare and return data based on the form input. I have one parameter in the prepared statement, which is taken from the form data, and set using the PDO `bindParam` method.

Using the form data, the json data I get back is undefined. If I hardcode the string parameter rather than use the form data, I get back the data I'm looking for. I've echoed out the exact value and type of the variable I'm passing in, and it's the same as the hardcoded string. I've tried explicitly setting the encoding to ensure it's utf8 as well.

This is what my php looks like (EDIT: includes execute method, which is included in my code, but got left out initially in the post):

```
$endorsers = array();
// Takes in the values from checkbox form data
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
  if($v == 'on') {
    $endorsers[] = $k;
  }
}

// Set variable to first checkbox value
$endorser = $endorsers[0];

try {
  $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=*****;charset=utf8', $username, $password);
  $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $statement = $connection->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT c.name AS cand_name, e.name AS end_name FROM candidates c JOIN end_cand ec ON (ec.end_id = c.id) JOIN endorsements e ON (e.abbrev = :endorser)');
  $statement->bindParam(':endorser', $endorser, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $statement->execute();

  $results = $statement->fetchAll();

  if (isset($results)) {
    echo json_encode($results);
  } else {
    $error = array('error_message' => 'Sorry, Charlie');
    echo json_encode($error);
  }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

And the ajax:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "get-endorsements.php",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data[0]);
                console.log(data[1]);
            }
        })
    })
});
```

If I do a regular form submission just to view the echoed json encoded results, I get the same thing whether using a hardcoded string or the form data - it's in this form:

```
[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key1":"value3","key2":"value4"}].
```

The data returned via ajax is undefined when using the form data variable though, and I can't figure out why this is making a difference.

SOLUTION:

```
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = $(this).serialize();
      console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            url: "get-endorsements.php",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data[0]);
                console.log(data[1]);
            }
        })
    })
```

Had to pass in data via `$.ajax` (thanks @David-SkyMesh), and NOT set the contentType (since this is the contentType for data passed to the server, not data received). Got myself very confused thinking that the data was available simply via the `$_POST` variable b/c it was, of course, when I tested the PHP return values with a standard post method on the form instead of via Ajax.

Comment: Have you checked the actual HTTP response using Chrome Developer Tools/Firebug/Fiddler?

Comment: It was returning html/text, so I added a header to my php to set the content type to json. Didn't change the results though, my data is still undefined.

Comment: @nicolekanderson Am I imagining things, or do you never pass the form data to be POSTed (i.e: your data-stucture to be JSONified) to `.ajax(...)` ? I see the configuration properties, the URL and the callbacks, but no data?

Comment: so you are saying it is undefined only when you use bindParm but it works when harcoded?

Answer (score 0):

I think you lost:

$results->execute();

before

$results = $statement->fetchAll();

```
$endorsers = array();
// Takes in the values from checkbox form data
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
  if($v == 'on') {
    $endorsers[] = $k;
  }
}

// Set variable to first checkbox value
$endorser = $endorsers[0];

try {
  $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=*****;charset=utf8', $username, $password);
  $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $statement = $connection->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT c.name AS cand_name, e.name AS end_name FROM candidates c JOIN end_cand ec ON (ec.end_id = c.id) JOIN endorsements e ON (e.abbrev = :endorser)');
  $statement->bindParam(':endorser', $endorser, PDO::PARAM_STR);

  $results->execute();
  $results = $statement->fetchAll();

  if (isset($results)) {
    echo json_encode($results);
  } else {
    $error = array('error_message' => 'Sorry, Charlie');
    echo json_encode($error);
  }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Right, sorry that got cut out when cleaning up my trouble-shooting code. I updated my post.